# wrong $_GET request

Tags: php, get

I have a URL:

```
http://missk.co.uk/index.php/admin/catalog_category/index/key/a47a4f77942acca6e40cdca9736d2a3d/

var_export($_GET) :

array ( '/index_php/admin/catalog_category/index/key/a47a4f77942acca6e40cdca9736d2a3d/' => '', )
```

Why I receive not the empty array though $ _GET has to give out parameters only after a question mark?

Comment: where are you seeing this url? If it's in your browser, then you probably have a rewrite occuring on the server. there's no way the existing url would show up in $_GET, since $_GET is built off anything that comes after a `?`, of which you have none.

Comment: It is correctly! In it and an error that here $ _GET has to be empty. These are the PHP or Nginx settings?

Answer (score 1):

I believe, that this is being caused by rewrite module in web server. Check your .htaccess file for RewriteRule.